# How can I view at once the cost incurred by all my Azure OpenAI resources for the current month or the last 30 days?

Tags: azure, azure-cost-management

I created several Azure OpenAI resources in my Azure account via https://portal.azure.com. How can I view at once the cost incurred by all my Azure OpenAI resources for the current month or the last 30 days? I don't want to have to check the cost for each resource one by one ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JaDN.png)), especially since cost management pages on https://portal.azure.com takes a while to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each resource is assigned to a subscription:

[image]

One can view the cost of all resources assigned to a subscription by going to https://portal.azure.com/#home, and clicking on the subscription name:

[image]

Subscriptions also have a cost management page, just like for resources:

[image]

One can view the breakdown by resource at the bottom right of the page.